# nodejs mongoose error TS2551: Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type 'Document'. Did you mean '$isDeleted'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a field in document and save the instance.

But I get this error message:

```
error TS2551: Property 'isDeleted' does not exist on type 'Document'. Did you mean '$isDeleted'
```

Model:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

const RambleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        default: 'https://static.wixstatic.com/...'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    pdfLink: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isArchived: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

const Ramble = mongoose.model('Rambles', RambleSchema);

export default Ramble;
```

Controller:

```
private deleteMorningRambles = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            const { id } = request.params;
            const ramble = await Ramble.findById(id);
            if (ramble == null) {
                return response.status(404).json({ message: "Cannot find ramble" });
            }
            ramble.isDeleted = true; // here is the issue
            await ramble.save();
            response.status(200).send({ status: "success" });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Shouldn't a call `mongoose.model` be as a generic one?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a `typescript` error rather than a `mongoose` error.

you have defined your schema like this

`const Ramble = mongoose.model('Rambles', RambleSchema);`

and you haven't defined the type for your `Ramble` model, hence typescirpt defines it for you with Generic type of `Document`.

So,in this line
`const ramble = await Ramble.findById(id);`

when you are trying to access findById() from your `Ramble` model, it returns the response in your `ramble` constant, which will also get `document` type. Hence it will give you that error.

So to avoid this, either you can define a specific type for your `Ramble` model or to quick fix assign type `any` for your `ramble` constant.